# Composer - Substantial drift from celery problem

Tags: composer-php, celery, drift

I'm getting Substantial drift from celery@ may mean clocks are out of sync. Current drift is 17 seconds.

I've read that this issue can be related to NTP clock synchronization, but I'm uncertain about how to resolve it.

Could you please suggest me how to fix this?

Comment: It means you need to setup time synchronisation (using NTP) on all machines running Celery workers.

Comment: Are you sure this problem is in any way related to Composer, or to programming?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.